# Script to execute a command in a loop

Tags: linux, loops, grep, shared-libraries

For my task I'm required to search through a list of services for a specific shared library.
I began by extracting all the directories for the services into a .txt file like so...

```
whereis sshd >> list.txt 
whereis sendmail >> list.txt 
....
```

Now I want to run the following command with the directories being output from the file I saved them to, something like this.

```
readelf list.txt | grep servicename >> results.txt
```

I'm guessing its do-able with a bash loop or script, but I'm just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

For reading dependencies shared libraries you have to use :

```
ldd /usr/sbin/sshd > sshd.txt
```

For each service you should create a *.txt file then remove duplicated shared libraries at `final.txt`

Comment: Is there way to use the ldd like...
    ldd list.txt | grep servicename >> results.txt

Comment: I tested and read manual of `readelf` it dooesn't get shared libraries.

Comment: it identifies needed librarys though. When you run the command readelf /usr/sbin/sshd | grep -i "librwrap"  - It returns the corresponding libwrap library dependencies